# C# run app as different user or schtasks auth

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, process, windows-task-scheduler

I was hoping I could get some input on the best way to handle authentication for my application.  I have a C# form that has three buttons.  One button is for querying tasks on a specific server, one button can start a task, and the last button can end a task.

My question involves the best way to do this for multiple users.  I know I can add these users to the administrator group on each server but I really don't want to do this because these are all non-admin users.  Also, I am running this against 3 different domains and multiple servers with no trusts.

Is there a way to either create a user that I can give admin rights on all of the servers and then run the C# app as this user (could be domain or local) or is there a better way to handle permissions for schtasks without giving admin rights?

I have researched impersonation but I don't think that does what I need unless I missed something.

Thank you,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`runas`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490994.aspx) command - this lets you set a user name and password to execute the application under.

You will still need to set the link up for each user/computer.

Comment: I just looked at the runas command and it looks like it might work.  What do you mean set the link?  If the account that C# is running as exists then it should work right?  (keeping in mind that I will need to run schtasks as the physical user's credentials.)

Comment: @Matt - I meant the shortcut or batch file that you use `runas` with.